# EF 5 and WebSite conflict

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm having problems with a website project and entityframework 5.

I'm going to put some background: The project type is Website, not web application or MVC, so when deploying, I simply copy all the files to the server and all is compiled when the first visit arrives. And that is what i think is causing the problem.

The project is targeting .Net 4.0 so when I install EntityFramework from nuget, the dll file version is 4.4. Running the project from VisualStudio with IIS Express is fine ( because VisualStudio knows that the target framework is 4 and compiles the project using .Net framework 4 dll ) but when copying the files to the production server where .Net framework 4.5 is installed, when first visit arrives, the website is compiled against the .Net framework 4.5 dlls and a problem appears because EntityFramework 4.4 contains definitions for classes ( like Column ) that are also contained inside the dataannotations dll from .Net 4.5.

```
The type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKeyAttribute' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll' and  'c:\Users\jyuste\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\portalempleado\4700d3ec\2c948b16\assembly\dl3\1c8b81c9\750c5018_1e5dce01\EntityFramework.DLL'
```

I suppose that upgrading the project to .Net 4.5 and updating the EntityFramework reference would solve the problem, but I can't do it right now.

Do you think that there is another solution?

Comment: Does your `web.config` contain `<compilation ... targetFramework="4.0" />`?

Comment: Yes: <compilation targetFramework="4.0"><assemblies><add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" /> ... </assemblies></compilation>

Answer (score 0):

From what you write, a possible solution would be to change the deployment procedure.

Instead of copying C# source files to a destination server, first publish the site locally to any directory. Publishing could be done with the "Build/Publish Web Site" option from the VS menu.

This will compile all your source files and create a deployment-ready sturcture containing only declarative code (*.aspx,*.ascx,*.asmx,etc) and the **/bin** folder containing *.dlls with compiled C# code.

Only then copy the published structure to the destiation server.

Comment: Yes, I already had been thought this possibility, but one requisite from the client is the ability to change code on the server.

I think that my options are: Change the target framework or downgrade the .Net version on the server.